# Is embedding a directory supported for cross-compilation?

Tags: go, embed, cross-compiling

**Summary of the problem**: access to embedded files in directories work for a native compilation but not for cross-compiled code

I have the following code that embeds a file (`static/index.html`) in a directory and exposes it via HTTP:

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

//go:embed static
var content embed.FS


func main() {
    // API and static site
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Use(mux.CORSMethodMiddleware(r))
    r.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, next)
    })
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowCredentials: true,
        //Debug: true,
    })
    handler := c.Handler(r)
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))
    log.Info().Msg("starting dash webserver at port 1495")
    _ = http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:1495", handler)
}
```

I compiled this code (`go1.16.7`) in Windows 10 WSL2 (EDIT: and in native Windows 10) via `go build -o goembed.wsl2`. When started, running `curl localhost:1495` gives the right result (the text in `index.html`).

I then compiled it (still in WSL2/Win10) via `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o goembed.linux` (or the relevant incantation in Windows 10 to set the environment variables) and started `goembed.linux` on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

The program started but the output of `curl localhost:1495` was `404 File Not Found`.

Why is it so?

Interestingly, embedding a single file (the variable containing it is then of type `[]byte`) exposes it correctly via the HTTP server in both binaries (the native WSL one, and the amd64).

EDIT: I have the same behaviour when compiling in native Windows 10, I updated the references above

Comment: I'm not at a Windows machine to double-check, but I would expect that `GOOS` defaults to `linux` under WSL2, since it's pretending to be Linux, so the "cross-compilation" here may be a red herring.

Comment: I have also seen numerous issues caused by interaction with WSL itself, and usually recommend avoiding it and using the native OS whenever possible.

Comment: @Adrian: I just tried in native Windows 10 - same issue

Comment: @JimB: I just tried in native Windows 10 - same issue

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake from my side: I embed `static` but serve `./static/` which is the **local (OS)** directory, instead of the embedded one. It should be:

```
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(content)))
```